# How to install specific of MySQL using apt package manager

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, apt, apt-get

I want to install a specific version of MySQL on my Ubuntu machine. Is there a way to install it using the package manager 'apt' or 'apt-get'?

In a normal installation, I'm getting MySQL 5.6 and when I try with MySQL documentation for MySQL 8, it installs version 8.0.25.

I looked into installing specific version of a package using 'package=version' in ubuntu with this [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779919/install-specific-version-of-openjdk)

But, is that possible in the case of MySQL. If possible, where can I get the available version list? I want to install MySQL version 8.0.21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install a specific version, we have to use [Archives](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)

Download version 8.0.21 based on your system architecture from the archives

To unpack it, use this command with root access

`tar -xvf mysql-server_MVER-DVER_CPU.deb-bundle.tar`

You may need to install the libaio library if it is not already present on your system:

`sudo apt-get install libaio1`

For a basic installation of the MySQL server, install the database common files package, the client package, the client metapackage, the server package, and the server metapackage (in that order); you can do that with a single command:

`sudo dpkg -i mysql-{common,community-client,client,community-server,server}_*.deb`

For more details regarding installing and setup visit : [MySQL installation guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/linux-installation-debian.html)

Comment: I need to install MySQL 8.0.21. Is that possible to install that version using apt?